# Python complex subpackage importing

Tags: python, python-import

I have a pretty complex package tree like the following within yet another package

```
A\
    B\
        a.py
        b.py
        c.py
    C\
        a.py
        b.py
        c.py
```

I want to be able to do `import A` and access all sub-packages and submodules like `A.B.a.foo()`.  One way would be to have `A/__init__.py` import all of `A`'s subpackages, but some of the subpackages also import other subpackages (e.g., `A.C` uses things from `A.B`, leading to an `ImportError`.  What I'm looking for is a way to do `from A import B as A.B`, i.e., import subpackages but still have them be bound to the parent package.  Is there a good way to do this?

(I'm not sure what title embodies this question, if someone has a better title then I'll change it.)

Comment: You have a circular import there, and this usually means that you have some design flaw in your package. If both `B` and `C` need each other, then they should be probably merged into a single package.

Comment: @Bakuriu I don't think that's necessarily or universally true (although it's probably true more often than it's false). Sometimes I have two packages that are conceptually pretty distinct even if their implementations are a bit intermingled, requiring some co-dependence. It's not pretty, but in some cases it could be worse to merge everything together.   edit: I realize you said "probably", not "definitely", but I still wanted to make the other argument.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

In `A.__init__`:

```
import B
import C
```

In `B.__init__`:

```
import C, a, b, c
```

In `C.__init__`:

```
import B, a, b, c
```

I tried this with some test files and it seemed to work fine.

```
In [5]: import A

In [6]: A.
A.B  A.C  

In [6]: A.B.
A.B.C  A.B.a  A.B.b  A.B.c
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import anything in `__init__.py` (just make sure that each package has this file on Python <3.3).

If you need to use `A.B.a.foo()` function in a module then add the corresponding import in it:

```
from A.B.a import foo
```